# Firebird - return count of fields not equal to null using select inside SP

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird

I need to write a Firebird store procedure to check 4 fields value and return the count only of the ones that are not null.

For example in pseudo code:

```
  X = 0; //is the count variable

  if field_1 is not null then X = 1;
  if field_2 is not null then X = X + 1;
  if field_3 is not null then X = X + 1;
  if field_4 is not null then X = X + 1;
```

But I want to ask if it is possible to do it inside a single Select?

I am using Firebird 2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get this sum per row, then using [IIF](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-iif.html) function like Welliam suggested would do.

But in case you want to get only one sum over all rows, use the aggregate function `COUNT` with explicit fieldname

```
select count(Field_1) + count(Field_2) + count(Field_3) + count(Field_4)
   from SomeTable;
```

as in that case it counts rows where the specified field is not NULL.

Comment: yes this would be better than using two functions and long syntax `Sum(IIF...)`......thanks ain

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the `IIF` function, like this:

```
select IIF(Field_1 is null, 0, 1)
     + IIF(Field_2 is null, 0, 1)
     + IIF(Field_3 is null, 0, 1)
     + IIF(Field_4 is null, 0, 1)
  from SomeTable;
```